# Get table name from struct in gorm.io

Tags: go-gorm

How do we get the name of the table for an arbitrary struct (that may or may not have a custom naming strategy)?
For example, the name of the Users table, that doesn't have a TableName function.
In v1 I could do `tableName := db.NewScope(&User{}).TableName()` but that is no longer supported in the current version v2.

How can I get the table name?

I have found a way to do it by running a finaliser:

`table_name := db.First(&WantToKnowTheTableForThisStruct{}).Statement.Table`

This seems like a bad hack. Running a finaliser seems clunky and unnecessary. I don't want to run a query for items in the table, I just want to know the table name.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using reflection to get the struct name, then apply what Gorm's convention is for table names: `GORM pluralizes struct name to snake_cases as table name, for struct User, its table name is users by convention`

Comment: To make it less hacky (i.e., avoid hitting the DB unnecessarily), you can use `db.DryRun = true` like: `db.Session(&gorm.Session{DryRun: true}).First...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like gorm.Statement provides access to the schema.

```
func GetSchema(table any) *schema.Schema {
    stmt := &gorm.Statement{DB: DB}
    stmt.Parse(table)
    return stmt.Schema
}

func main() {
    tableSchema := GetSchema(MyTable{})
    fmt.Println(tableSchema.Table)
}
```

Gorm Playground link: https://github.com/twocs/playground/tree/tablename